# How can I restore the Developer Tools window to its normal configuration?

Tags: microsoft-edge, developer-tools

I have Edge  95.0.1020.53, in Win 10 Pro 21H1.

I'm not a techie. For no specific reason, I opened Developer Tools, which I haven't done for about 10 years.

After opening, I saw the configuration that I've seen many times: the parent web page using three-quarters of the complete window was on the left. The tools were in a panel on the right.

After pressing several buttons out of curiosity, I'm unable to get back to my original config, with the current web page on the right, and the tools on the left. The web page is no longer visible The dev tools take up the complete window. I suspect that I might have actually dragged the leftmost edge of Dev Tools all the way to the right of the main window. If I could somehow grab that left edge and drag it to the right, I think my problem would be solved.

In an attempt to restore the "default" config, I restarted my laptop. But if I show Dev Tools, I still get the palette of windows that I opened earlier. The parent web page is not visible.

How can I "reset" the config to its default config?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to reset the dev tools to restore the default in Edge, just follow the steps below:

1. Open Edge and press `F12` to open the dev tools
2. Press `F1` to open the settings panel when focus in dev tools
3. Scroll the `Preference` tab to the bottom
4. Click the option `Restore default and refresh`

Just like this:

[image]

Comment: Xudong Peng:  Thank you for your detailed step-by-step answer and screenshot. I have now restored Dev Tools to its default config.